# Windows 10 Visual State Manager Wide Stae not being triggered

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, visualstatemanager

I am following the case study porting WP [Silverlight to UWP here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/wpsl-to-uwp-case-study-bookstore2)

I noticed the `WideState` `wideSeZo` is not triggered even when the condition `MinWindowWidth="548"` is satisfied  if the XAML is placed inside MainPage.xaml. Instead, the `narrowSeZo` is shown for both Windows Phone and Desktop.

My MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="Bookstore2Universal_10.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:Bookstore2Universal_10="using:Bookstore2Universal_10"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.DataContext>
    <Bookstore2Universal_10:BookstoreViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="BookstoreStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="AuthorHasACollectionOfBookSku"
        Source="{Binding Authors}"
        IsSourceGrouped="true"
        ItemsPath="BookSkus"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</Page.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Margin="{StaticResource TitlePanelMargin}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding AppName}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Margin="9.6,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PageTitle}" Margin="7.2,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="9.6,0">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="WideState">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="548"/>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="wideSeZo.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter Target="narrowSeZo.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <SemanticZoom x:Name="wideSeZo" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
                <GridView
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AuthorHasACollectionOfBookSku}}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BookTemplateWide}"
            ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ZoomedInItemsPanelTemplate}">
                    <GridView.GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle
                    HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource AuthorGroupHeaderTemplateWide}"
                    HidesIfEmpty="True"/>
                    </GridView.GroupStyle>
                </GridView>
            </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
            <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
                <GridView
            ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionGroups, Source={StaticResource AuthorHasACollectionOfBookSku}}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ZoomedOutAuthorTemplateWide}"/>
            </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
        </SemanticZoom>

        <SemanticZoom x:Name="narrowSeZo">
            <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
                <ListView
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AuthorHasACollectionOfBookSku}}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BookTemplate}">
                    <ListView.GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle
                    HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource AuthorGroupHeaderContainerStyle}"
                    HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource AuthorGroupHeaderTemplate}"
                    HidesIfEmpty="True"/>
                    </ListView.GroupStyle>
                </ListView>
            </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
            <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
                <ListView
            ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionGroups, Source={StaticResource AuthorHasACollectionOfBookSku}}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ZoomedOutAuthorTemplate}"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ZoomedOutAuthorItemContainerStyle}"/>
            </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
        </SemanticZoom>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

However if I place the code in a User Control named SeZoUC.xaml the `WideState` is being triggered properly

`MainPage.xaml` with the`SeZoUC.xaml` usercontrol.

```
<Page
x:Class="Bookstore2Universal_10.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:Bookstore2Universal_10="using:Bookstore2Universal_10"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.DataContext>
    <Bookstore2Universal_10:BookstoreViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="BookstoreStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Margin="{StaticResource TitlePanelMargin}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding AppName}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Margin="9.6,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PageTitle}" Margin="7.2,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="9.6,0">
        <Bookstore2Universal_10:SeZoUC/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

The `SeZoUC.xaml` code

```
<UserControl
x:Class="Bookstore2Universal_10.SeZoUC"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Bookstore2Universal_10"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="BookstoreStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="AuthorHasACollectionOfBookSku"
        Source="{Binding Authors}"
        IsSourceGrouped="true"
        ItemsPath="BookSkus"/>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="WideState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="548"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="wideSeZo.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Target="narrowSeZo.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <SemanticZoom x:Name="wideSeZo" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
            <GridView
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AuthorHasACollectionOfBookSku}}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BookTemplateWide}"
            ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ZoomedInItemsPanelTemplate}">
                <GridView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle
                    HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource AuthorGroupHeaderTemplateWide}"
                    HidesIfEmpty="True"/>
                </GridView.GroupStyle>
            </GridView>
        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
            <GridView
            ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionGroups, Source={StaticResource AuthorHasACollectionOfBookSku}}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ZoomedOutAuthorTemplateWide}"/>
        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
    </SemanticZoom>

    <SemanticZoom x:Name="narrowSeZo">
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
            <ListView
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AuthorHasACollectionOfBookSku}}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BookTemplate}">
                <ListView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle
                    HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource AuthorGroupHeaderContainerStyle}"
                    HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource AuthorGroupHeaderTemplate}"
                    HidesIfEmpty="True"/>
                </ListView.GroupStyle>
            </ListView>
        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
            <ListView
            ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionGroups, Source={StaticResource AuthorHasACollectionOfBookSku}}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ZoomedOutAuthorTemplate}"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ZoomedOutAuthorItemContainerStyle}"/>
        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
    </SemanticZoom>

</Grid>
```

My BookstoreStyles.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives"
xmlns:Bookstore2Universal_10="using:Bookstore2Universal_10">

<Thickness x:Key="TitlePanelMargin">0</Thickness>

<Style x:Key="AuthorGroupHeaderContainerStyle" TargetType="ListViewHeaderItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ZoomedOutAuthorItemContainerStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
</Style>

<DataTemplate x:Key="AuthorGroupHeaderTemplateWide">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="AuthorGroupHeaderTemplate">
    <Border Margin="0,0,0,9.6" Background="{StaticResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="9.6,0,0,4.8" Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>

<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ZoomedInItemsPanelTemplate">
    <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" GroupPadding="0,0,0,20"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>

<Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives:JumpListItemBackgroundConverter x:Key="JumpListItemBackgroundConverter" />
<Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives:JumpListItemForegroundConverter x:Key="JumpListItemForegroundConverter" />

<DataTemplate x:Key="ZoomedOutAuthorTemplateWide">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250" Height="250" >
        <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
            <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" Height="80" Margin="15,0" Text="{Binding Group.Name}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ZoomedOutAuthorTemplate">
    <Border Margin="9.6,0.8" Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource JumpListItemBackgroundConverter}}">
        <TextBlock Margin="9.6,0,9.6,4.8" Text="{Binding Group.Name}" Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource JumpListItemForegroundConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="BookTemplateWide">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250" Height="250">
        <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
        <Image Source="{Binding CoverImage}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Margin="12,0,24,0" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Author.Name}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Margin="12,0,12,12"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="BookTemplate">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,8">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Width="56" Height="56">
            <Image Source="{Binding CoverImage}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Border>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="9.6,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Author.Name}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="9.6,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br209007):

> When you use StateTriggers, ensure that the VisualStateGroup is declared under the first child of the root in order for the triggers to take effect automatically.

You'll need to move your VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups so that it's directly underneath the first child of the root element for it to work in MainPage.xaml. The root element in MainPage.xaml is `<Page>`, so the first child (not counting attached properties) is `<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">` and that's where your VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups needs to be:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="WideState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="548"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="wideSeZo.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Target="narrowSeZo.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <!-- ... -->
```